# Why one of my JFrame don't open/show on external jar file?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, swing, export

I have a electronic phone book application with MySql, everything works just fine in my Eclipse, BUT... when i export runnable jar file, when i run my program everything works fine except that one of my JFrame dont want to show (but it show only in eclipse. no erorrs no nothing, i dont know what to do) ...i talk about my frame where the user can add data to database.

my code for showing that JFrame is this

```
if (conectat) {
    try {
        PaginaAdd frameAdd = new PaginaAdd();
        if (VariabileGlobale.pagAdd == "NU") {
            VariabileGlobale.pagAdd = "DA";
            // sa aiba iconita
            try {
                frameAdd.setIconImage(
                        ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data-add-icon.png")));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // terminare sa aiba iconita
            frameAdd.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frameAdd.setVisible(true);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} else
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are not connected to database!", " Electronic Phone Book",
            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
```

Please help. I dont understand why in eclipse work and why on exported jar file not working :((

Comment: One obvious problem is how you compare Strings. Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: So not `if (VariabileGlobale.pagAdd == "NU") {` but rather `if (VariabileGlobale.pagAdd.equals("NU")) {`

Comment: Other suggestion: create a command window, and run your jar from the command window so you can see any exception stacktrace messages that might be thrown.

Comment: thanks for the answers but... i tryed with equals as u suggested...the same...not working on runnable jar...how to run my jar pls... from command window?

Comment: @CristianBabarusi `java -jar {you jar name}.jar`

Comment: ok seems it worked...are some problems...can u tell me what is about?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
        at cnbi.AgendaTelefon.Java.GUI.PaginaAdd.<init>(PaginaAdd.java:388)
        at cnbi.AgendaTelefon.Java.GUI.PaginaPrincipala$9.actionPerformed(PaginaPrincipala.java:371)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)

Comment: @CristianBabarusi `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data-add-icon.png")));` is likely throwing an exception because the named resource can not be found within the current class-path context. Make sure that the resource is been included in the jar at the root level - you can unzip the Jar to inspect it

Comment: is included i dont see any errors :(, i dont know what to do and how to solve it..i was sure is about a image or something but, if i dont get any errors and works perfect in eclipse i dont understand why give me error in the exported jar file...how to include that file in there pls?

Comment: OMG after search internet...and of course with your HELP man, because you told me about the command console running.. i finded the problem. Is a conflict beetweend some other images and buttons in my frameAdd because they both use the same names...ohh i need to rearrange all.... i will come back with an complete answer ( maybe will help others )

Comment: Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. Glad you got it sorted! :)

Comment: ok @AndrewThompson ... got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of user "MadProgrammer" i was able to figure and solve my problem.
Also with this i learned how to use a very importand JAVA command console for running my jar files, where is showing everyting in execution of the program. Soo the command that i used to find the problems is this

```
java -jar myExecutableNameFile.jar
```

And my problem was this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at cnbi.AgendaTelefon.Java.GUI.PaginaAdd.<init>(PaginaAdd.java:388)
    at cnbi.AgendaTelefon.Java.GUI.PaginaPrincipala$9.actionPerformed(PaginaPrincipala.java:371)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
```

My solution was to remove a duplicat image (that has similar name with the current menu image who was calling that jframe to be visible). After i deleted the code and inserted the correct one with new image path... everything works perfect now.

I want to thanks once again to you "MadProgrammer" because you saved me. I was searching to solve this for 5 hours until you came :)